React-native-maps white screen, Map not rendering
I use  MapView installed from react-native-maps to create map tha covers  the home screen
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';

const Home = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title: 'Location Permission',
            message: 'This app needs access to your location to show maps.',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          },
        );
        if (granted !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('Location permission denied');
        }
      }
    };

    requestLocationPermission();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default Home;

Output
Check Map Permissions: Ensure that your app has the necessary permissions to access location services. Without these permissions, the map might not render properly.
Check for Errors: Open the console or log output of your development environment to check for any errors or warnings. These can provide clues about what might be going wrong.
Use a Map API Key: If you are using the Google Maps provider, ensure that you have a valid API key and that it is correctly configured. The absence of a key or an invalid key can cause the map to fail to load.

When integrating react-native-maps into your React Native application on Android, it's crucial to include your Google Maps API key in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY" />


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
